# Nhibernate queryover union

Tags: nhibernate, union, queryover

I have two queries based in session.QueryOver. The queries are different, but returns a IList the same type object.
The number of result of the two query, is the total object that i need.

How can I combine both queryover?

Is possible to do a union in NHibernate?

Answer (score 0):

You could consider using CreateSQLQuery instead. Form your SQL query syntax with the UNION keyword and use CreateSQLQuery to execute your query and get your result.

```
ISessionFactory.OpenSession().CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM A UNION SELECT * FROM B")
                             .SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(YourClass)))
                             .List<YourClass>();
```